# Fastest SVM library in R for large data and Multiclass problem

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, e1071

I try to implement SVM on a very large data set.

My Data is categorical with three classes. I have tried `e1071`, but it took too long to solve my problem.

Anyone who knows the best and fastest library for solving my problem?

Comment: You might be better to ask this on an R-specific site. Before you do I suggest adding more detail explaining what very large and too long mean for you.

Answer (score 2):

"[LiblineaR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LiblineaR/index.html)" can be used on large data sets. Alternatively, you may try [H2O](http://www.h2o.ai/) libraries.